# javascript - Trying to get site to add values

Tags: javascript

I'm not brilliant at Javascript and I'm just trying to do something that seems basic, but just can't figure it out. Looking for some assistance. Here's the code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" 
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<title>Chapter 8: Question 1</title>

<script type="text/javascript">
function updatebox()
{
    var textbox = document.getElementById("list")
    var total = Number('0')
    textbox.value = ""



    if (document.getElementById('A1').checked) {
        textbox.value = total + Number('5');
    }

    else if(document.getElementById('A1')) {
        textbox.value = total + Number('0');
    }

    if (document.getElementById('A2').checked) {
        textbox.value = total + Number('5');
    }

    else if(document.getElementById('A2')) {
        textbox.value = total + Number('0');
    }

}
</script>

</head>

<form>
    Processor
    ...
    CD-ROM (+$5.00)
    <input type="checkbox" name="chkCDROM" id="A1" onclick="updatebox()" />

    DVD-ROM (+$5.00)
    <input type="checkbox" name="chkDVD" id="A2" onclick="updatebox()" />

</form>

</html>
```

---

The goal is to grab these various factors, add them up, and put them in the textbox as they are clicked. I can get it to work using several variables, but then got thrown off with the second list of dropdown menus I had and needed to remove them. I put them back in the original script, which is why they are a little different. Please let me know what I may be doing wrong here.

Comment: I find it interesting that you use `Number()`.

Comment: well I wasn't originally using number, I had it set up with variables, and was doing things like A, A + B, A + B + C and that worked up until I couldn't really do that too well for the 2 drop down menus, so then I switched everything out trying to use the Number function, where I kind of blew my mind even more.

Comment: But why not just use integers?

Comment: You mean as in: int()?

Comment: No, I mean `5` as opposed to `Number('5')`

Comment: Oh, it wasn't working that way either :p

Comment: You also should put your `<form>` into a `<body>`

Comment: @Maccesch But it is a form...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you need to actually store an updated value in total. Secondly, I think you'll find it easier if you try something more like this

```
var total = 0;
textbox.value = "";

if(document.getElementById('A1').checked) {
  total += 5;
}
// the rest of your if(s)... and then
textbox.value = total;
```

Comment: Thank you, thank you, thank you, thank you so much!!!!  This was extremely thankful and literally fixed everything!

Answer (score 0):

There are several things that I would change about your code

- Not use `Number()`, just use the number. It's easier and better
- Use `<label>`s (there are many advantages for this)
- Update the `total`, then set the value of the displaying input at the end of the function
- Use `+=` to update the total for each element
- Use the attribute `value` to actually give the value. Use the javascript `e.options[e.selectedIndex].value` to get the value and add it to the total

Here's the great thing: I've done them all for you! (:

[**Here's the updated version**](http://jsfiddle.net/Zeaklous/5GhAh/)

Comment: I appreciate this as well. See I am helping a family member with their class and Javascript isn't really my forte. I'm trying my best and everything helps. Again, I want to thank you for this as well.

Comment: @user3051039 I'm betting you have a background in a programming language like Java (:

Comment: While I have you here though, might I ask how we would go about putting the results of this into seperate frame (with framesets) without changing the initial code? or would I have to make some adjustments?

Comment: From Mozilla: `Because the use of frames is now discouraged in favor of using <iframe>, this element is not typically used by modern web sites.` Why do you want to do it in a frame anyway?

Comment: While I realize it may be discouraged upon, just need it as part of the next tutorial for her. Her assignment is calling for using framesets for the same idea as I was doing above, but just taking the result and have it open in a frame. Her teacher's code was almost nigh-unreadable for me and I resulted in making my own code which is what is above. I figured if I can read it, my family member can understand it.